# Facing problem to load data first time in MaterialTable in React

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am new to react and redux. I am using MaterialTable and wanted to load data via redux in server-side pagination example. But the problem is when I use remote data from redux. it is not loaded by default. it seems table got render before props update.

I am new to react and redux. I am using MaterialTable and wanted to load data via redux in server-side pagination example. But the problem is when I use remote data from redux. it is not loaded by default. it seems table got render before props update.

//VehichleList Component

````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { getVehichles } from "../../store/actions/vehichleActions";
import axios from "axios";


class vehichleActionButtons extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.tableRef = React.createRef();
 }

 refreshTableData = () => {
 if(this.tableRef.current) {
 this.tableRef.current.onQueryChange()
 } 
 }


 render() {

 return (
     <Box m={6}>
     <Grid container>
         <Grid item xs>
         <Box m={2}> <MaterialTable
         tableRef={this.tableRef}
         columns={this.props.vehichles.columns}
         data={(query) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             this.props.getVehichles(query);
             resolve({
             data: this.props.vehichles.rows,
             page:query.page,
             totalCount: this.props.vehichles.totalCount,
             });
         })
         }
         title="Vehichle List"
         /></Box>
         </Grid>
     </Grid>
     </Box>
 );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

 return {
 vehichles: state.vehichle,
 };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
 getVehichles: (query) => dispatch(getVehichles(query)),
 };
};

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(vehichleActionButtons);

//action code is 

import axios from 'axios';
export const getVehichles = (query) => {
 return  (dispatch, getState) => {
     dispatch({ type: "GETTING_VEHICHLES_LIST"});
     let url = "http://my-json-server.typicode.com/mksrivastava/zwe/rows?";
     url += "_limit=" + query.pageSize;
     url += "&_page=" + (query.page + 1);
     axios.get(url).then(
     (resp) => {
         dispatch({ type: "GET_VEHICHLES_LIST", resp })},
     (error) =>
         dispatch({
         type: "GET_VEHICHLES_LIST_ERROR",
         error: error.message || "Unexpected Error!!!",
         })
     );

 };

}
//reducer code is 
const initState = {
 rows: [],
 columns: [
 { title: "Vehicle No", field: "vehicleNo" },
 { title: "Date of Reg", field: "dateOfReg", type: "date" },
 { title: "Status of Reg", field: "statusOfReg" },
 { title: "Engine Type", field: "EngineType" },
 { title: "Modal Year", field: "year" },
 ],
 totalCount: 0,
 loaded: false
};

const vehichleReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
 case "GETTING_VEHICHLES_LIST":
     return {
     ...state,
     loaded:false
     }
 case "GET_VEHICHLES_LIST":
     return {
     ...state,
     rows: action.resp.data,
     totalCount: +action.resp.headers['x-total-count'],
     loaded:true
     }

 default:
     return state;
 }
};
export default vehichleReducer;```

Could someone please recheck and help me to solve this. It looks like the material table is not fully supported redux

Thanks in advance
````

Comment: You're mixing element-rendering with state changes. A state is just data; not components. Hence your state should be populated with the data, and when the data is present the MaterialTable should be rendered with the actual data as props.

Comment: Hi  have updated the component but still facing the same issue

Comment: You are still triggering this.props.getVehichles(query) on the render call. If you want to modify the state of the object you need to do this either before it gets rendered, or using a setState call.

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html for more info